# why is node just printing out what is in the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having issues with node.js, I'm not that familiar with it.

I have a JavaScript file that I need to load the file into node.js by using `.load "filename.js"`.

when I run the command I just get a print out of the code that is in the file.

here is my code for the file I'm trying to load. I have made the changes suggested to me. but I'm still getting an entire print out of code.

```
class ArithmeticTaskRunner 
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.tasks = [];
  }
  addNegationTask()
  {
    const negationTask = (x) => -x;
    this.tasks.push(negationTask)
    return this;
  }
  addAdditionTask(y)
  {
    const additionByY = (x) => x + y;
    this.tasks.push(additionByY)
    return this;
  }
  addMultiplicationTask(y)
  {
    const multiplyByY = (x) => x * y;
    this.tasks.push(multiplyByY)
    return this;
  }
  taskCount()
  {
    return this.tasks.length;
  }
  execute(n)
  {
    let currentResult = n;
    for(let task of this.tasks)
    {
        currentResult = task(currentResult)
    }
    return currentResult;
  }
}
let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)
taskRunner.addNegationTask()
taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask() 
taskRunner.execute(2)
```

here are examples of the output and the input that is needed on this task

1.

> let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
>       undefined
>   taskRunner.addAdditionTask(2)
>       undefined
>   taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask(4)
>       undefined
>   taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)
>       undefined
>   taskRunner.execute(2)
>       26
>   taskRunner.execute(-2)
>       10

2.

> taskRunner.execute()
>       -5
>   taskRunner.execute(10)
>       -10
>   taskRunner.taskCount
>       3

Comment: Please show your code so we can help you.

Comment: in the examples i have added to the post now they show the required input that will be used and the output in the terminal, that I where I need to end up. rather than getting the file reprinted in terminal or a failed to load

Comment: In regards to your update, you should then just do the class definition in your `ArithmeticTaskRunner.js` file. When you load the file you should be able to execute those instructions in the Node REPL.

Comment: when I try to load the file in node.js I rather get a reprint of the entire file when using .load ArithmeticTaskRunner.js, if i try to load the file in node.js with .load ArithmeticTaskRunner.js let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner() i get failed to load

Comment: But that's what `.load` is supposed to. To load the file into the current REPL session. What do you want to achieve exactly? Do you have to use `.load`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a REPL session and run the commands in command line you can use `repl` module.

```
const repl = require('repl');

class ArithmeticTaskRunner {
  ... // Your class definition
}

// This starts the REPL session with the ArithmeticTaskRunner defined
repl.start().context.ArithmeticTaskRunner = ArithmeticTaskRunner;
```

Then in terminal:

```
node filename.js
```

And when you have node running:

```
let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(2)
taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask(4)
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)
taskRunner.execute(2)
taskRunner.execute(-2)
```

If you want to run the code completely and output the result use `console.log` in the code and run `node filename.js`:

```
class ArithmeticTaskRunner {
  ... // Your class definition
}

let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(2)
taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask(4)
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)

console.log(taskRunner.execute(2))
console.log(taskRunner.execute(-2))
```

In terminal:

```
node filename.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've done basically the following on the command line:

```
node
.load ArithmeticTaskRunner.js
```

The reason you're only seeing the code printed out is because you just have a class definition. You don't have an instance of `TaskRunner`. If that's your intent, at the bottom of your code add something like this:

```
const taskRunner = new TaskRunner();
console.log(taskRunner);
```

Then when you try those command line steps again, it will print out an instance of `TaskRunner` with your methods on it.

However, the entire purpose of the `.load` command is to put your script into the Node.js REPL. Alternatively you can instead do the following in the command line:

```
node
.load ArithmeticTaskRunner.js
const taskRunner = new TaskRunner();
console.log(taskRunner);
```

This will let you do work on the command line without hard-coding it into your script.

**Update**

If your intent is to execute the code without printing it out, you can do the following:

```
node ArithmeticTaskRunner.js
```

But you won't be making your code available to the global instance. You'd have to add code into that script that creates a 'TaskRunner` instance and make use of it, like I did initially and save it into that file.

```
class ArithmeticTaskRunner 
{
    constructor()
    {
      this.tasks = [];
    }
    addNegationTask()
    {
      const negationTask = (x) => -x;
      this.tasks.push(negationTask)
      return this;
    }
    addAdditionTask(y)
    {
      const additionByY = (x) => x + y;
      this.tasks.push(additionByY)
      return this;
    }
    addMultiplicationTask(y)
    {
        const multiplyByY = (x) => x * y;
        this.tasks.push(multiplyByY)
        return this;
    }
    taskCount()
    {
      return this.tasks.length;
    }
    execute(n)
    {
        let currentResult = n;
        for(let task of this.tasks)
        {
            currentResult = task(currentResult)
        }
        return currentResult;
    }
}
const arithmeticTaskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner ();
console.log(arithmeticTaskRunner );
```

After this then try doing the steps on the command line:

```
node
.load ArithmeticTaskRunner.js
```

**Update 2**

This should open the Node REPL (leading '>` should appear). Afterwards do these commands one line at a time:

```
let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(2)
taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask(4)
taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)
taskRunner.execute(2)
```

This should print 26.

```
taskRunner.execute(-2)
```

This should print 10.

Comment: I've made the changes suggested by you but I'm still getting the entire file printed back to me in the terminal.

Comment: it was slightly, I now get a failed to load in the terminal in node.js when I use the command .load ArithmeticTaskRunner.js let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()

Comment: Are you sending those commands one at a time? Try `.load ArithmeticTaskRunner.js` and then `let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()`

Comment: yeah, I believe that's the way that it needs doing, I haven't really got much to go on, the brief I have for this task doesn't explain a lot

Comment: no matter what i do as soon as i use the ".load" it instantly prints the whole file to the terminal

Comment: It seems that the printing out is the default behavior after using `.load`. Is it enough if the command prompt window just hides the lines where it printed the file? If so you can try adding the following at the bottom of your `ArithmeticTaskRunner.js` file: `console.log('\033[2J');`

Comment: I'm getting an error now on the word file: and when ran I get a print out of the whole file again with syntax error pointing to the line you just gave me.

Comment: if i try to run all the commands at once i get failed to load

Comment: What terminal are you running this in? This works for Command Prompt, Bash, and Powershell just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186234/discussion-between-joe-and-modzking4).